# W/System.err: com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: schema mismatch for Tweet.Amitabh; expected Array but got String

Tags: java, android, arrays, parse-server

this is the code for updating the value of the key "Amithabh" but the `put` method is giving error. The `add` and `remove` methods are working properly. The server is fine connected

```
package com.example.androidparse;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.parse.GetCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Tweet");
        query.getInBackground("qDGilscXDH", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                if(e == null){
//                    object.add("Amitabh","KBC");
                    object.put("Amitabh","kbc");
                    object.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });

                    Log.i("string",object.get("Amitabh").toString());
                    Log.i("success","saved succesfull");
                }else{
                    Log.i("not saved",e.getStackTrace().toString());
                }
            }
        });

        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    }
}
```

[the code to update value at parse server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvU9g.png)

> Output error

```
W/System.err: com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: schema mismatch for Tweet.Amitabh; expected Array but got String
W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseRequest.newPermanentException(ParseRequest.java:268)
        at com.parse.ParseRESTCommand.onResponseAsync(ParseRESTCommand.java:302)
        at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:134)
W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:130)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$15.run(Task.java:907)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:113)
W/System.err:     at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:898)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:713)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:724)
W/System.err:     at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$13.then(Task.java:816)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$13.then(Task.java:804)
W/System.err:     at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$15.run(Task.java:907)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

[error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VP08.png)